# AssertEqual doesn't show the same information as AssertEquals

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.6

As in Python 3, `AssertEquals` is deprecated and should be replaced with `AssertEqual`. However, the latter doesn't convey the same information. It doesn't show the difference.

e.g.

```
self.assertEquals(result.status_code, 403)
```

> File ".pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 822, in _baseAssertEqual
>       raise self.failureException(msg)
>   AssertionError: 404 != 403

Great, `AssertionError: 404 != 403` this is very useful. But the AssertEqual is like this:

> File "projects/x_api/tests/test_apply_voucher.py", line 16, in
>   test_add_invalid_code
>       self.assertEqual(result.status_code, 403)

That's not very useful, it doesn't show me the content of `result.status_code`. Do I have to use it differently?

Comment: If you look at [the implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/unittest/case.py#L1342), `assertEquals` actually calls `assertEqual` after showing the warning; the same method is called, the behaviour is identical. Please give a [mcve] recreating this issue.

Comment: I tested it in python 3.6.4 and got the exact same output from both methods.

Comment: I think you're looking in the wrong place. The "AssertionError 404 != 403" should be above the stack trace, not appended after the line with the `raise`.

Comment: @BaileyParker You are right. As I was editing the question I figured out the output has changed. The result goes now above the stack trace instead of the bottom. I wasn't used to that. So there is clearly a difference.